# Warning when type casting a constant to short int in C

Tags: c, casting, integer, compiler-warnings, short

I get the warning like this warning "C4310: cast truncates constant value".
associated code is

```
short a = 100;
if( a == (short)0x8000 ) ;// Warning is got here.
```

Whats the way to remove the warning without making 0x8000 as constant or variable value and without type casting a?

if i modify the condition line to

```
if( a == (short)-32768 ) ;// No warning seen
```

Why is this?

Thank you.

Comment: @Fredrik: Without the cast, the condition is always false.

Comment: @R..  Thank you and i used the method of using negative numbers instead of type casting.

Comment: @Seena Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Answer (score 3):

The warning is telling you something important.

Assuming a `short` is 16 bit, valid values are -32768 to 32767.  The value `0x8000` (32768) falls outside the range of a `short`.

Using -32768 works because it fits within the range of a `short`, and in fact a cast is not needed in this case.

Comment: Is `0x8000` truncated to `0`?

Comment: No, it's truncated to -0x8000.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Yes, the constant would have fit into an `unsigned short` so it would have worked.  Whether it fits what OP intended is another story.

Answer (score 1):

The key problem that the warning is trying to express to you is that in your C implementation, type `short` cannot represent the value `0x8000`.  Such implementations are not at all unusual, for it is common that `short` has a 16-bit representation, of which one is a sign bit.  The cast has implementation-defined behavior, and very likely *not* the behavior you expect.

Moreover, without the cast, the equality comparison will always evaluate to false, because, again, `short` cannot represent the given value, therefore no possible value of `a` is equal to that value.

You want to use a different type for `a`.  If you use a type that can represent `0x8000` (`unsigned short` and signed and unsigned `int` will all satisfy that criterion) then you will not need to cast.  There may be other considerations relevant to which type you should choose, but you haven't presented any.

Answer (score 0):

You pretty much have two options:

1. Write the constant with the value you want it to have after conversion so that the cast can be omitted:

   ```
   if( a == -0x8000 )
   ```

   or,
2. Disable the warning, as it's specifically preventing you from doing what you want to do: using casts as operators that change values. (A cast that's value-preserving is usually useless, except possibly controlling the type the surrounding expression is evaluated in.)

Comment: It wasn't me, and this is `short`, but perhaps related to the definition `#define INT_MIN (-2147483647 - 1)` because using `-2147483648` will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `unsigned short` so you can use all the bits as you don't care about signs:

```
unsigned short a = 100;
if( a == 0x8000 )
```